# Problems with Doctrine 2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

My code:

**bootstrap.php**

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;

$paths = array(dirname(__FILE__)."/entities");
require_once __DIR__ . '/entities/Users.php';

$isDevMode = false;
// the connection configuration
$dbParams = array(
    'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
    'user'     => 'root',
    'password' => 'pass',
    'dbname'   => 'p1db',
);

$config = Setup::createConfiguration($isDevMode);
$driver = new AnnotationDriver(new AnnotationReader(), $paths);

// registering noop annotation autoloader - allow all annotations by default
AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader('class_exists');
$config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driver);
$config->setSQLLogger(new \Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\EchoSQLLogger());

$em = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);
```

**test.php**

```
<?php 
include 'bootstrap.php';
....
 try {
     $user = new Users();
     $user->setName($_POST['name']);
     $user->setEmail($_POST['email']);
     $user->setPassword(sha1($_POST['password'] . $_SALT_));
     $user->setPhone($_POST['phone']);
     $em->persist($user);
     $em->flush();
 } catch (Exception $e) {
     $em->getConnection()->rollback();
     $em->close();
     throw $e;
 }
```

I can't understand why it's not working. When it runs `$em->flush()` I got page freez for 3-4 seconds and then `Error 103 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED): Unknown error`
I did some debug here. I set up mysql logging, here what I have in MySQL log after execuing the code above:

```
   13 Query START TRANSACTION
   13 Query INSERT INTO users (email, password, name, added_date, phone) VALUES ('foo@example.com', 'ec4cea0c00610c486f52e62e2850fa7e8b95fb04', 'test name', NULL, '5555555')
```

If I execute this queries in MySQL shell - they work fine.
I found that the problem is in `\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->commit()`, on the line `$conn->beginTransaction();`. `beginTransaction()` is defined here `\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Connection->beginTransaction()`
But this is just an interface... I have no idea what's going on here.

MySQL v 5.1.48, pdo_mysql

```
PDO Driver for MySQL    enabled
Client API version  mysqlnd 5.0.8-dev - 20102224 - $Revision: 308673 $
```

Comment: This is a PDO problem, not really a Doctrine 2 ORM problem. Are you on windows? If so, then you should check if your `php5ts.dll` is up to date.

Comment: Yeah, it was old php5ts.dll :) thanks!